# Read this array in php

Tags: php, arrays

My PHP received this string from an Android app

```
[{"id":2,"category":"Food%2C%20Drinks%20%26%20Clothes","description":"Nasi%20Lemak%2C%20Teh%20Tarik%20","cost":"5","transactionDate":"2016-10-04"},{"id":3,"category":"Food%2C%20Drinks%20%26%20Clothes","description":"Rori%20Canai","cost":"3"}]
```

Then after doing `$data = json_decode($data,TRUE);`

to the string above, it become:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category] => Food%2C%20Drinks%20%26%20Clothes
            [description] => Nasi%20Lemak%2C%20Teh%20Tarik%20
            [cost] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [category] => Food%2C%20Drinks%20%26%20Clothes
            [description] => Roti%20Canai
            [cost] => 3
        )

)
```

But I don't know how to read it. Here's what I did:

```
//I pass the data above into variable $data

$data = json_decode($data,TRUE);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){    
 echo "id: ".$data[$i]["id"]. ", desc: ".$data[$i]["description"]. ", cost: ".$data[$i]["cost"];
}
```

but it just outputs A A A...

*All the data above is already displayed in `<pre></pre>`

Comment: What's the actual value of `$data` before you decode? What do you get if you `var_dump($data)` after decoding? Also, I'd suggest assigning to a different variable name.

Comment: did you use somewhere `urlencode()`? if yes then use `rawurlencode()` instead of it.

Comment: This works fine https://3v4l.org/2Znq2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save json to variable, for example `$json`, and run `json_decode($json, true)` and save it to variable, for example `$array`. Now you have decoded json in array. After that you can iterate through array using `foreach` loop. To get rid of some `%2C%...` characters, run `urldecode`on every element of subarray. This is an example:

```
<?php

$json = '[{"id":2,"category":"Food%2C%20Drinks%20%26%20Clothes","description":"Nasi%20Lemak%2C%20Teh%20Tarik%20","cost":"5","transactionDate":"2016-10-04"},{"id":3,"category":"Food%2C%20Drinks%20%26%20Clothes","description":"Rori%20Canai","cost":"3"}]
';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($array as $subArray)
{
    echo urldecode($subArray['id']).'<br/>';
    echo urldecode($subArray['category']).'<br/>';
    echo urldecode($subArray['description']).'<br/>';
    echo urldecode($subArray['cost']).'<br/><br/>';
}
```

And result is:

```
2
Food, Drinks & Clothes
Nasi Lemak, Teh Tarik 
5

3
Food, Drinks & Clothes
Rori Canai
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk_recursive(json_decode($json, true), function(&$item, $key){
    $item = urldecode($item);
});

foreach ($array as $item) {
    ..
}
```